# Kendoui web checkbox data binding

Tags: html, django, json, grid, kendo-ui

Hi I'm not sure if i'm using the right words in the title, please correct me if not. I've been working for almost a month with kendo ui. It's really good. 
Now my problem, i'm working with html, django and kendo. I'm getting information from a url in json format. I'm able to load the information in a Kendo Grid, with a boolean values column and a text column. In the boolean values column i've found a way to turn it into a checkbox input column with a field template and set its checked value according to the data i got from the url. The problem is that I can't manage to bind the checked value to the data in the grid's datasource, so when I click the save button to save the new information I get the same data I got from the url. Does anybody know how to do this or a simpler way to do it instead of mine? Thank you!

Comment: Try providing some code samples to supplement your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a code library project which covers almost the same scenario. You could use the same idea to update the underlying model which the Grid uses.

http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/checkbox-column-and-incell-editing.aspx